# How many people brought sacrifices to the tabernacle at the same time?

Tags: number, korban, mishkan-tabernacle

With over 600,000 male Israelites required to offer sacrifices at the Tabernacle, how many males came at one time? This seems to comprise an enormous logistical difficulty.

Comment: Why do you think they all had to come all the time or at the same time? Maybe they went years without offering something.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Don't be so hard on him. It's a nice question.

Comment: Pirkei Avot 5:5 (text and translation from Sefaria)

" עֲשָׂרָה נִסִּים נַעֲשׂוּ לַאֲבוֹתֵינוּ בְּבֵית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ. ... עוֹמְדִים צְפוּפִים וּמִשְׁתַּחֲוִים רְוָחִים" = 

"Ten miracles were performed for our forefathers in the Temple ... They would stand up crowded and bow down with [enough] space."

The Beit Hamikdash (Temple) was a miraculous place. I'm not sure logistics were such an issue for anything involved with the service there.

Comment: @ezra I don't understand what was so hard. Do you see what is the enormous logistical difficulty that he refers to? Maybe you can enlighten me.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Assuming all the Israelites brought there korbanos at the same time, how would so many people be able to fit in the courtyard of the Tabernacle?

Comment: @ezra But that doesn't seem like a good assumption. A question based on a not good assumption isn't good. That's why I asked him why he thought that assumption was worth assuming.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 cases when everybody had to bring a sacrifice: Pessach and Festivals.

For Korban Pessach they had more than 1 person per animal - usually a family (or more) per animal. But even then they divided the crowd into 3 - and they sacrificed the Pessach in 3 groups.

They had an entire procedure as described in the Mishna in Pesachim to make the process efficient.

The Chagigah and Re'iya that had to be brought at each of the 3 festivals, one had 7 days (8 on Sukkoth) to bring them - so that would have alleviated the rush somewhat.

There's a Mishna that says that the Temple Courtyard was filled to capacity before dawn with people lining up to bring their sacrifices - so I guess it was simply done on a first-come-first-serve basis.

Comment: I don't think Re'iya applied in the Mishkan? The OP seems to ask about the Mishkan only; not the later Mikdash.

Comment: The Mishna about the courtyard being filled to capacity is in Yoma IIRC

Comment: @DavidKenner - can you source that? (Re'iya didn't apply in the Mishkan)